# Vue nested data: child component not hidden when parent node is deleted

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have Vue displaying a few copies of a component according to the data `source` in the root instance. The data is a nested JS object with children. Pointers to parent nodes are added once the data is loaded. In the view I can drill down and up, displaying one level of the hierarchy at a time. No recursion is used in the view.

My question is: Why don't the child components disappear when their parent node is deleted?

Please ignore the lengthy CSS: it's part of larger project and not relevant to the question at hand.

Since SO snippets don't display this well, here's a CodePen: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/RmWOWE. The difficulty is that it still doesn't allow you to fire up Vue DevTools and peek under the hood so I'll try and simplify further or get a standalone page up.

```js
var source = {
  "name": "root",
  "value": 9,
  "id": 0,
  "children": [{
    "name": "Nodes",
    "value": 32,
    "id": 100,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Fish",
      "value": 20,
      "id": 1,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Cod",
        "value": 5,
        "id": 10,
      },{
        "name": "Salmon",
        "value": 15,
        "id": 110,
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Drinks",
      "value": 12,
      "id": 3,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Juice",
        "value": 8,
        "id": 11,
      },
      {
        "name": "Wine",
        "value": 4,
        "id": 12,
      }]
    }]
  }]
};


function clone(obj) {
  /* Standard clone function */
  if(obj === null || typeof(obj) !== 'object' || 'isActiveClone' in obj)
  return obj;
  var temp = obj.constructor(); // changed
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
      obj['isActiveClone'] = null;
      temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
      delete obj['isActiveClone'];
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

Vue.component('bar-wrapper', {
  props: ['node', 'index', 'side'],
  template: '#bar-wrapper',
  methods: {
    amount(node) {
      // bar.value = bar.old_value / 100 * this.root;
      return Math.abs(node.value / node.parent.value) * 100;
    },
    drillDown(side, node, event) {
      this.$emit('drill-to', side, node);
    }
  }
});


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: {
    db: {
      tree: clone(source)
    },
    expenses: {
      children: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    expenses_view_nodes() {
      return this.expenses.children;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    amount(node) {
      return Math.abs(node.value / node.parent.value) * 100;
    },
    compare(a, b) {
      if (Math.abs(a.value) < Math.abs(b.value))
      return 1;
      if (Math.abs(a.value) > Math.abs(b.value))
      return -1;
      return 0;
    },
    makeParents(node) {
      var _this = this;
      if (!node.hasOwnProperty("children"))
      return false;
      else {
        var parent_node = node;
        $.each(node.children, function() {
          this.parent = parent_node;
          _this.makeParents(this);
        });
      }
      return node;
    },
    sortMe() {
      if (this.expenses && this.expenses.children) {
        this.expenses.children.sort(this.compare);
      }
      return false;
    },
    drillDown(side, node) {
      this.expenses = node;
    },
    drillUp(side, node, event) {
      if (node.parent && node.parent.id != 0) {
        this.expenses = node.parent;
      }
    },
    insertCake() {
      this.db.tree.children[0].children.push({id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000), name: "Cake", value: 14, parent: this.db.tree.children[0]});
      this.db.tree.children[0].value += 14;
    },
    deleteFish() {
      var this_amount = this.db.tree.children[0].children[0].value;
      this.db.tree.children[0].children.splice(0,1);
      this.db.tree.children[0].value -= this_amount;
    },
    deleteChild() {
      // Vue.delete(this.db.tree.children[0].children[0].children, 0);
      var this_amount = this.db.tree.children[0].children[0].children[0].value;
      this.db.tree.children[0].children[0].children.splice(0,1);
      this.db.tree.children[0].children[0].value -= this_amount;
      this.db.tree.children[0].value -= this_amount;
    },
    init() {
      this.db.tree = clone(source);
      this.expenses = this.db.tree.children[0];
      this.makeParents(this.db.tree);
      this.sortMe();
    }
  },
  watch: {
    db: {
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log("Watched the db");
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    console.log("%cBefore create hook: Component is not created and data variables are not available yet", "color:green");
  },
  created() {
    console.log("%cCreated hook: Component is created and data variables are available", "color:green");
    this.init();
  },
  beforeMount() {
    console.log("%cBefore mount hook: Component is not mounted on DOM yet", "color:green");
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("%cMounted hook: Component is mounted on DOM", "color:green");
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    console.log("%cBefore update hook: Component is not updated yet", "color:green");
  },
  updated() {
    console.log("%cUpdated hook: Component is updated", "color:green");
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log("%cBefore destroy hook: Component is about to be destroyed", "color:green");
  },
  destroyed() {
    console.log("%cDestroyed hook: Component is destroyed", "color:green");
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #659B5E;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #3c5c37;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.charts {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: move;
  transition: all 1s;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px; }

.chart {
  position: relative;
}

.chart-left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5%; }

.chart-right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0.5%; }

.bar-wrapper {
  position: relative; }

.bar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  .bar.parent {
    cursor: pointer; }
    .bar.parent .bar-label > a:after {
      content: '\02026'; }
  .bar:not(.parent) {
    cursor: default; }


.chart-left .bar-wrapper {
    transform-origin: right center;
    height: 64px;
}

.chart-right .bar-wrapper {
    transform-origin: left center;
    height: 64px;
}

.bar-label {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none; }
  .bar-label > a {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.2s, color 0.2s, text-shadow 0.2s;
    pointer-events: auto;
    text-decoration: none; }
    .bar-label > a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline; }
    .bar-label > a.no-description {
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: default; }
  .bar-label .popover-footer {
    padding: 9px 14px 9px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "type edit"; }
    .bar-label .popover-footer .node-type {
      grid-area: type;
      color: #bbb;
      text-transform: uppercase; }
      .bar-label .popover-footer .node-type .fa, .bar-label .popover-footer .node-type .fas, .bar-label .popover-footer .node-type .far {
        margin-right: 10px; }
    .bar-label .popover-footer .node-edit {
      grid-area: edit;
      text-align: right; }
      .bar-label .popover-footer .node-edit a {
        pointer-events: auto;
        display: none; }


.chart-left .bar-fluid .bar-label {
  left: 0%;
  padding-left: 22px; }
.chart-left .bar-fixed .bar-label {
  left: 0%;
  padding-left: 12px; }
.chart-left .compare {
  right: 0%;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding-left: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto; }
.chart-left .bar-label .popover {
  left: -40px !important;
  right: auto !important; }
.chart-left .bar-label > a {
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: -3px 0px 4px #f46d43, 3px 0px 4px #f46d43, 0px 3px 4px #f46d43, 0px -3px 4px #f46d43; }
  .chart-left .bar-label > a.outside {
    text-align: right; }

.charts .bar-label > a.outside {
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #999; }

.chart-left .bar {
  background: linear-gradient(#f14813 4%, #f46d43 5%, #f14813 95%, #f79273 96%);
  background-position: left top;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0px;
  overflow: visible !important; }
  .chart-left .bar:hover .sub-bar {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #ffffff; }

.chart-left bar.bar-fluid {
  background: linear-gradient(#f14813 4%, #f46d43 5%, #f14813 95%, #f79273 96%); }

.chart-left .bar-fixed {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 10px, transparent 10px, transparent 20px), linear-gradient(#f14813 4%, #f46d43 5%, #f14813 95%, #f79273 96%); }

.bar-fixed .bar-handle {
  display: none; }

.chart-left .bar.hiding {
  -webkit-animation: remove-left 0.5s ease forwards;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: remove-left 0.5s ease forwards; }

.chart-left .bar.showing {
  -webkit-animation: add-left 0.5s ease forwards;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: add-left 0.5s ease forwards; }

.amount, .charts .percentage {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap; }

.chart-left .bar-fixed .amount, .chart-left .bar-fixed .percentage {
  text-align: right;
  right: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px; }
.chart-left .bar-fluid .amount, .chart-left .bar-fluid .percentage, .chart-left .compare .amount, .chart-left .compare .percentage {
  text-align: right;
  right: 100%;
  padding-right: 22px; }

.chart-right .bar-fixed .amount, .chart-right .bar-fixed .percentage {
  text-align: left;
  left: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px; }
.chart-right .bar-fluid .amount, .chart-right .bar-fluid .percentage, .chart-right .compare .amount, .chart-right .compare .percentage {
  text-align: left;
  left: 100%;
  padding-left: 22px; }

.shadowed {
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }


.chart-left .line, .chart-left .sub-bar {
  right: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); }

.chart-right .line, .chart-right .sub-bar {
  left: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); }

.sub-bar {
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;

  text-align: center; }
  .sub-bar span {
    display: none; }

.chart-left .sub-bar {
  right: 0px;
}

.chart-right .sub-bar {
  left: 0px;
}



body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.chart {
  float: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.bars {
  height: 300px;
}

.bar {
  height: 34px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.sub-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}

.list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.tools {
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.tools button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/x-template" id="bar-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="bar bar-fluid" v-bind:style="{display: 'flex', 'flex-direction': 'row-reverse', 'padding': 0, transition: 'none', width: amount(node) + '%'}">
      <div class="sub-bar" v-for="(no, index) in node.children" v-bind:key="no.id" v-bind:style="{position: 'static', width: amount(no) + '%'}"></div>
      <div class="bar-label" style="top: 5px">
        <a v-if="node.children" @click.stop.prevent="drillDown(side, node, $event)">{{node.name}}...</a>
        <span v-else>{{node.name}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>


<div id="main">

  <center>
    <p>
      <i>Click on a bar label to drill down. Click on the chart background to come back up.</i>
    </p>
    <b>
      <p>
        <u>How to reproduce:</u> Click on <kbd>Fish...</kbd>, then click on <kbd>Delete Fish</kbd> button.
      </p>
      <p>
        <u>Question:</u> Why does the view not update when I am looking at Cod and Salmon (inside Fish), and I delete the Fish node?
      </p>
    </b>
  </center>

  <div class="tools">
    <button @click="deleteFish">Delete Fish</button>
    <button @click="deleteChild">Delete first child</button>
    <button @click="insertCake">Insert Cake</button>
    <button @click="sortMe">Sort</button>
    <button @click="init">Reset</button>
  </div>


  <div class="charts">
    <div class="chart chart-left" @click="drillUp(0, expenses, $event)">

      <transition-group name="list" tag="div" class="bars">
        <bar-wrapper v-on:drill-to="drillDown" v-for="(node, index) in expenses_view_nodes" :key="node.id" class="wrapper" :node="node" :index="index" :side="0" :style="{position: 'absolute', top: index * 60 + 'px'}"></bar-wrapper>
      </transition-group>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's a heck of a lot of code. You might get more folks to look at your question if you can reduce it to a minimal set.

Comment: Yes I agree it is. It took me over an hour to boil it down to this.

Comment: Try reducing it to a simple case that can be extended to your actual problem.

Comment: Any reason for not using recursion in the template?

Comment: @Francisco Hanna - I'm not using recursion because the chart could be very deep but I am really only showing one level at a time.

Comment: So, you want the DOM to update when you change a value in the controller? Then you may have to use Vue's [two-way data binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) with `v-model`

Comment: Also, you may want to drill-up to the parent of the node that is beign deleted

Comment: Yes, if there are no other children left, but I've not done that here to show that the child components are not being removed eventhough their data is no longer in the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193067/discussion-between-francisco-hanna-and-msc).

Comment: After some side experiments, I see that in JS, splicing an element from an array doesn't remove it from memory, so my `expenses_view_nodes` is still valid, eventhough the node's been removed from the parent's `children` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS, splicing an element from an array doesn't remove it from memory, so my `expenses_view_nodes` is still valid, eventhough the node's been removed from the parent's children array.

The way I resolve this is - after deleting the Fish node - to check whether the view pointer (`expenses_view_nodes`) points to a node that is still in the tree. If not, change it to point to Fish's parent node (`id = 100`). Vue then redraws as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When removing items from an array in Vue, try wrapping the actual `.splice` operation in `setTimeout`.

Instead of something like:

```
del: function(item) {
  this.list.splice(this.list.indexOf(item), 1);
}
```

do this:

```
del: function(item) {
  var list = this.list, index = list.indexOf(item);
  setTimeout(function() { list.splice(index, 1); }, 0);
}
```